# Eevee live action over text

Tags: video

Has anyone got an Eevee tutorial on how to put moving images over part of a text word created in 2.8?
I have a video of a person walking across the screen and I want to put a huge word behind the person. I found this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILFo9YDHGa8 but it's from an older version of Blender and I want a step-by-step Eevee version. The effect that the guy got is exactly what I want (he even leans over and puts his arm behind the text - but that's for another time).
Is there an Eevee tutorial out there?[image]

Comment: The tutorial you've found doesn't need a Eevee specific version, because the method doesn't depend on the render engine in the first place. The important parts are the masking of the original footage which is done in the movie clip editor which hasn't changed in the 2.8 versions (except the color theme) and doesn't interact with the render engine. The only Eevee thing you need to know is how to make a basic material for your text and make a render, which is nothing fancy and can be found on any beginner tutorial for Eevee.

Comment: Thanks for your reply LOLock.